# Adapter initially has no data, Synchronization issue

Tags: java, android, synchronization, adapter

I have written a `CustomAdapterView`. My issue is that my `CustomAdapterView` runs `onLayout` before it even has data.

The sequence is as follows:

`onCreate` ==> `setAdapter` ==> `requestLayout` ==> `onLayout` // No Data!

`onResume` ==> `call to server` ==> `callback returns server data` //Too late! onLayout won't run now!

Even if I use `notifyDataSetChanged` this has no effect since `notifyDataSetChanged` only affects views which are currently existing. There are no views in my layout.

So the question I have is, what is the proper way to handle an adapter that initially has no data?

I know that I can force call `onLayout` or `requestLayout` in my asynchronous thread, but it seems unnecessary to force that call each time `onResume` runs. Afterall, this is a 1 time issue (the first time the person opens my app).

So is that my best option? Or is there some way to have `setAdapter` wait for the adapter data to change first?

My data is initialized in the UI thread in `oncreate` as `JSONArray data = new JSONArray();`

It is subsequently changed with `data = newJSONArray(response)` in the callback, where response is the JSON string response provided by my server.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, I created a new thread to do a while loop that `requestLayout`. I considered a volatile variable but didn't think it was necessary here...